# ZXing on Android - Decode performance extremely slow

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

As the title suggests, I am trying to decode QR codes on an Android device using ZXing's Barcode Scanner app. I have read multiple threads on the internet about how it is discouraged to integrate the app within one's own project. Instead, one should use `IntentIntegrator`.

However, this is not an option in my case. Below is a snippet of code which I am calling for every camera frame.

```
LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap);
BinaryBitmap bm = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

try {
    Result result = reader.decode(bm); // This line takes approx. 6seconds
    if (!result.getText().isEmpty()) {
        Log.e("MYTAG", "Found something: "+result.getText());
    }
}
catch (NotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ChecksumException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As I said, this process is extremely slow. Decoding takes anywhere between 5 to 8 seconds.

I have tried using both the `MultiFormatReader` and the `QRCodeReader`.

Can anyone shed some light on the subject?

Comment: can u put your answer. I had same problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out that the performance suffers greatly with the Android debugger attached to the application. Approximate time taken to scan a full camera frame image on an HTC Desire HD takes around 150ms - 200ms. Silly mistake on my part.

Comment: Thank you! Been ripping my hair out on this. Detached the debugger and hey presto it reads the code in a fraction of the time.

Comment: Detaching debugger didn't help. Only rebuilding in release mode made the speed of decoding the same as other zxing-using apps I found in play market.

Answer (score 1):

I only use ZXing via intent and it is very fast that way - to throw an idea in here: perhaps the input image is too large - perhaps reduce the size before throwing it into the decoder ..

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why you want to scan by Intent -- no coding or debugging, and you scan optimally.

Here I imagine you are feeding it a full 5MP image or something. Don't do that.

Comment: Some additional information: my company's using the zxing library to do decoding from various hardware barcode scanners. 640x480 and 752x480 are the most common preview sizes that we use; both work fine.

Comment: That's fine then, those preview sizes are easy to crunch. A cycle finishes in about 150ms for me. Are you turning on TRY_HARDER? That's also something you shouldn't do on mobile.

Comment: Also, why RGBLuminanceSource? You would use YUVPlanarLuminanceSource with preview data.

Answer (score 0):

The decoding performance will depend on your phone CPU speed as well. For a given phone/tablet, performance will not increase beyond a particular point because this library works on ARM/ACPU.

You may have to work on optimizing your app. Moreover, you can:

1. Use intent method so that threads will be different.
2. Try to feed lower resolution image, so image processing will not take much of CPU.
3. Keep uniform inclination OR try to keep parallel plane between phone and barcode sticker/printed page.

Comment: May I ask, from your first point about intent methods using a different thread. Does that mean using an embedded zxing decoder uses UI thread ? like here : https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java